# How to override a package in android source code at boot-time?

Tags: android

I want the android source to check at boot time if sdcard is inserted and if yes
then override the default crypto package in the android source code with the one
in sd card, else it does nothing.

Now I have 2 questions:
1. How can i override a default package?
2. How to check the status of sdcard at boot time?

I know how to check the status of sdcard in an application, which i got from one of the
posts here, but how to utilize this boot time

if(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))

Regards,
Yogesh

Comment: Are you asking that question for a rooted device? Because I doubt that you would be able to do anything that changes the Android OS behaviour when booting.

Comment: Why put this on the SDCard and not in the ROM itself?  You are trying to go out of order.

Comment: @jhominal Yeah as of now its a research project so i am working on a rooted device, where i have downloaded source code and want to make changes in its source packages.
@Lucas B I want a plug n play type of functionality with my sdcard so that if the card is inserted new source files are made while compiling system image. But putting it in rom is also an option i'll looking from now on Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> 1. How can i override a default package?

You don't. You can create your own firmware that uses a different crypto package, and hope you don't break anything.

> 1. How to check the status of sdcard at boot time?

The SD card is not usable until very late in the boot process, after the home screen has launched. The snippet of source code you show should work -- the question is timing. For example, you can register a `BroadcastReceiver` to get control at "boot time" via the `BOOT_COMPLETED` broadcast, but it may get control before the SD card is mounted.

Comment: In that case i have to search more because creating a different crypto package doesn't serve my purpose as i want all apps installed on the device to run through my crypto package if it is present. Can you guide me where to look,i want to a functionality similar to ld_library_path in linux where a bunch of paths are defined and the first one which matches gets picked up.

Comment: @JoshMachine: You will need to create your own firmware, then.

Comment: Thanks but i think before working towards firmware, I'll give one more try by editing .bashrc file and adding ld_library_path to my sdcard and hope it works

Comment: You may not need to compile a new firmware from source, but you would have to change things on /system.  Probably you will need to bring up the sdcard earlier during boot (maybe temporarily), then you should copy the crypto library off of it and use the copy so your device doesn't crash if the sdcard is subsequently handed over to the mass storage function (which unmounts it as far as the phone is concerned).   You could then either figure out how library path support works or just use simlinks.  Keep in mind /system is normally mounted read only.

Comment: If you want to add your scripts just use nandroid to lift your boot image,  split-bootimage.pl  ( google for it )  and edit  init.rc files.    Then put it back on your device